# NSPredicate in CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift2, nspredicate

I am having trouble in understanding some code.

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "categoryId == %@ AND position == %i", categoryId, NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(categoryId) as! Int)
```

I dont know for what is used `%i`

Comment: for position, %i means integer

Comment: if position is equal to integer?

Comment: if position is equal to NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(categoryId)

Comment: Documentation for string format specifiers: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1